# use CSS to change a horizontal menu to be a responsive menu for mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML for me horizontal CSS menu:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Homepage</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Services</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><span>LINK</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Projects</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Contact Us</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Whats the best way to use css to make it a dropdown menu (like: http://responsive-nav.com/) when the page gets smaller.

i have made this menu dissapear when the page gets too small using media queries but i would like to just use CSS to change it to be like the menu (link above) and keep the same HTML.

here is a fiddle with the full code: *http://jsfiddle.net/auBpX/*

Comment: resize the nav so that each item is 100% wide maybe

Answer (score 0):

Your media queries should override the default styles so put them at the bottom of your css rather than the top.

I'm not going to code the whole thing but [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/auBpX/1/) might get you started.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    #cssmenu {height:10px; overflow:hidden;}
    #cssmenu:hover {height:auto; overflow:none;}
    #cssmenu li {display:block; width:100%; float:none;}
    ...
}
```